# Excel VBA - How to Insert Sequential Page Number

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to insert sequential page number across the entire workbook (there are two worksheets in the workbook.

Here is my code to insert page numbers:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Appendix A").PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&P of &N"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&P of &N"
```

Comment: let me know if what you wanted is in my answer below

Comment: The following line of VBA code will give you the page count for a sheet (based on the current page setup. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).PageSetup.Pages.Count` Yet, if a user is changing the page setup just before printing then you're out of luck. So, I'd suggest that you control printing altogether by offering a print button.

Comment: @Flower_Dance have you tested it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to write the index of the current sheet out of the entire number of sheets in your `ActiveWorkbook`, then use the following code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Appendix A").PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Page " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Appendix A").Index & " of " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Page " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Index & " of " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
```