Displaying header/footer page number alphabetically (abc) instead of numerically (123)
I'm trying to get page numbers to display as abc... etc. in the header
Although I'm not sure if it possible at all to manipulate the page numbers expression atleast in the way that I am trying to do so?
Any help would be appreciated, I'm out of my depth here.
'Here is a simplified version of my code:
Sub example()

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .RightHeader = Chr("&P" + 96)
        'returns type mismatch

End With
End Sub


'Also tried
        '.RightHeader = Chr(CStr("&P") + 96)
        'Type mismatch
        
        '.RightHeader = Replace(Replace(Replace("&P", "1", "a"), "2", "b"), "3", "c") etc.
        'which returns the page number unmodified

        '.RightHeader = Chr("1" + 96)
        'Proof of concept and what I'm aiming for, returns "a" in header when page number is "1"


On line 4 Chr("&P" + 96) is causing the type mismatch error because the function CHR() must have a numeric value as a parameter.

Yes, is it possible to force the "&P" into a numeric value? I have tried: = Chr(CInt("&P")) as well as Chr(CLng("&P")), this also returns type mismatch

The Microsoft documentation says that the value for .rightheader should be a text value. Try this .RightHeader = "&P" + CStr(96))

.RightHeader = "&P" + CStr(96) returns "196". There's no use of Chr() in this code. Did you mean something else?

Secondly, according to what I think I've understood, Chr() requires a numeric value & .RightHeader requires String/Text, so something like .RightHeader = CStr(Chr(CInt("&P")+96)) would be how I imagine the solution to be. But again, type mismatch

Try using exactly this ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Page " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Index & " of " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count and see if it work - ie gets rid of the error message. Then step 2 change .CenterFooter to .RightHeader and see if that works ... Then step 3 change ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Index to Chr(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Index + 64) and see if that does what you want. Inspired by this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256128/excel-vba-how-to-insert-sequential-page-number

I have now tried this & it does not return any errors, however it brings the incorrect information into the header, it is detailing the ordering of sheets within the workbook instead of the print pages within the sheet for example. If I have 6 sheets in my workbook and run a print preview, it will display "sheet A of 6" on every page in the print preview.

Good explanation ... please try this ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count  and ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count

I have experimented with PageBreaks.Count in a number of ways including in conjuction with your above code and I can see how it can be used to determine and display the total number of print pages, but it's not clear that they can be used to dynamically present the current number of the print page in the way that "&P" does (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Workbooks-and-Worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers which refers to these as "special formatting codes"). Is there a specific way that you would recommend use of PagePreaks? Thanks

Yes, agreed ...  I am still trying! How about ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=2 and set the page number page by page?

Understood, I am not at my computer until tomorrow now, then I will try with this. Thanks for your continued support.

This link has the exact same "solution" - print each page one at a time and set the header for each one. In your case convert to alphabetic page indexes as you do this with CHR(). This is a very old post from 2002 so Excel is different now. It may be worth asking a question here about if there is a property in Excel that is the PrintedPageNumber. Good question +1. Come back soon, stay longer :)

... and if you have more than 26 pages? https://superuser.com/questions/316239/how-to-get-the-current-column-name-in-excel

Understood, it's a bit of a work-around solution but I'll try it. Thanks
